# Potential Max CP of Wild Pokémon

Tags: pokemon-go

I noticed that somebody had a Pidgeot with a far higher CP than mine, which was maxed out for my level. Initially I thought that was just because I was a lower level trainer at the time - I was around 8 and he was about 20. But later on I thought that the difference (500cp versus 1200cp) was too big to be made just by leveling the trainer.

I began to think that maybe the CP of the Pokémon when they are caught makes a difference. Previously I had assumed that they would just need less.powering up to take them to max if they had a higher CP, but does a Pokémon's starting CP affect their max CP cap later on?

For clarity, if I found a 10 CP Pidgy and a 100 CP Pidgy, will one of them have a lower max CP cap or could I raise them both to the same level in time?

Comment: Max cp is decided b IV's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the difference in the CP is not too big for it just to be trainer level and is quite normal. A pokemon's starting CP will never affect their max CP cap because the cap moves with trainer level.

However a 10 CP pidgy with a higher IV than 100 CP pidgy will have a higher max CP cap simply because it has better base stats.

Link for IV calculator is [here](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator).

Comment: That calculator is pretty cool, but does it work for Go? It seems to be made for the regular game.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the comment. I linked the wrong IV calculator, the new link should be made for Go.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that - the calculator is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

The CP when getting a Pokémon don't have anything to do with the max CP it can reach. The individual values (IV) are setting the limits.

You can use [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wbtIc33K45iU1ScUnkB0PlslJ-eLaJlSZY47sPME2Uk) ([or this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZI2pfWL-pf_jqsPYfZgIgCFPqKwoxw5A2sErgU-UnB0/copy)) to narrow down the IV, which are responsible for the max CP.

(You might need a few tries to get the copy it asks you to make, since a lot of people are using it. In the meantime just read the description. It helps a lot.)